# Word game 3 checks and Jtextarea background color

Tags: java, cpu-word

I have to create a word game called "Lingo", so far everything is going well but lately I had problems occurring with the checks, in the game there are 3 checks.

```
//FIRST CHECK
        for (int i=0;i<input.length();i++){
        if(input.charAt(i)==CorrectWord.charAt(i)){
        LingoBoard[0][i].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
//WHEN every letter(input) matches the correct word = the background(TextArea) becomes                     green.

//SECOND CHECK

else { LingoBoard[0][i].setBackground(Color.RED); }
//When the letters do not match the letters from the correct word = TextArea becomes red

//THIRD CHECK
//When the letters are in the correct word but not in the right place = TextArea becomes      magenta
```

I'm stuck with the third check, i can't seem to find a way that can fix my problem.
i tried this, but it makes the background magenta for all 3 checks.

```
if((LingoBoard[0][i].getText().charAt(i)!=CorrectWord.charAt(i))){
            LingoBoard[0][i].setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way of matching a correct word is:

```
if(input.equals(CorrectWord)) {
    LingoBoard[0][i].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Though I'm surprised that your code works as you have no closing curly brace (`}`) after that first `if` statement. Could you post the whole class, if it's not too large?

For the second and third check, you're better off doing something like the following:

```
if(!(input.equals(CorrectWord))) {
    // create temporary array to match against
    ArrayList<Character> tempArray = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for(char c : input.toCharArray) {
        // create from copy of player's input
        tempArray.add(c);
    }

    // for each character in the solution
    for(char c : CorrectWord.toCharArray()) {
        // loop through the player's input
        for(char d : input.toCharArray()) {
            // and check if features there
            if(d == c) {
                tempArray.remove(d);
                // we only want to remove one char at a time, so break if found
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // if all the letters have been found, regardless of their order
    if(tempArray.size() == 0) {
        LingoBoard[0][i].setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
    } else {
        LingoBoard[0][i].setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Haven't tested the code, written it on the spot. I hate nested `for` loops but I haven't found a better way to handle `char` array manipulation.

Comment: @GorbI think the class i too big, can I send it to you another way? and in your code, the last lines, "i" is not defined anywhere

Comment: Just set up a count variable, or change my advanced for loop for your traditional for loop (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). With regards to sending the class; have you tried using the code I gave you?

Comment: Yes i tried your code but it gives an error at this point  tempArray.remove(c); java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 72, Size: 5.  not really sure with this means

Comment: * `tempArray.remove(d);` - got it the wrong way around, sorry. The error gives you the `Index`; the line number. It gives you the size of the array it can't reach; 5.

Comment: Still gives the same error :(, any way I can send you the whole class?

Comment: Ok here's the link http://pastebin.com/i0abKu0B Run it and ask anything if you have a question

Comment: `tempArray.add(new Character(c));` and `tempArray.remove(new Character(d));` stops the error. That said, your program has more issues than the coloured backgrounds.

Comment: the "new Character(c)" doesn't really fix anything, try running it. Thanks for your time in reading it and don't worry i'll fix up the code when i get the checks right :/

Comment: I got it loading on my computer; the `new Character(c)` stopped the error. Might still require further fixes though, as your program is quite broken.

Comment: Yeh i got it loading too, what i meant is that the check doesn't work, it automatically makes the background red, you should try playing the game, that is if you have the time @Gorb

Comment: I have played the game. Getting all the letters right works. Getting the letters wrong only highlights the first letter red. Magenta doesn't work at all. Not entering a word into the text box *crashes your program*. There are issues to work out!